# Lost character/s during encrypt-decrypt using <wincrypt.h>

Tags: c++, encryption

I am using "wincrypt.h" to based algorithms to encrypt a character string and then decrypt the encrypted string to the original.

Something like :

```
Original -> Encrypt -> Decrypt -> Original
```

The problem is the Decrypted Original comes out short in length in some case(some words), the problem is not length of the string or a or more character related, that I have checked. The problem I think is with key(its simply a random character string), If I use a different key, it affects a totally different word/string.

Here is the code:

```
    BOOL SetupCryptoClient()
    {
        // Ensure that the default cryptographic client is set up.  
        HCRYPTPROV hProv;
        HCRYPTKEY hKey;     
        // Attempt to acquire a handle to the default key container.
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))  
        {
            // Some sort of error occured, create default key container.
            if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET))
            {   
                // Error creating key container!            
                return FALSE;       
            }   
        }
        // Attempt to get handle to signature key.
        if (!CryptGetUserKey(hProv, AT_SIGNATURE, &hKey))   
        {
            if (GetLastError() == NTE_NO_KEY)       
            {           
                // Create signature key pair.
                if (!CryptGenKey(hProv, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, &hKey))            
                {
                    // Error during CryptGenKey!                
                    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                    return FALSE;           
                }           
                else            
                {               
                    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);          
                }       
            }       
            else        
            {
                // Error during CryptGetUserKey!            
                CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                return FALSE;       
            }   
        }

        // Attempt to get handle to exchange key.
        if (!CryptGetUserKey(hProv,AT_KEYEXCHANGE,&hKey))   
        {
            if (GetLastError()==NTE_NO_KEY)     
            {           
                // Create key exchange key pair.
                if (!CryptGenKey(hProv,AT_KEYEXCHANGE,0,&hKey))         
                {
                    // Error during CryptGenKey!                
                    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                    return FALSE;           
                }           
                else            
                {               
                    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);          
                }       
            }       
            else        
            {
                // Error during CryptGetUserKey!            
                CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                return FALSE;       
            }   
        }   

        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);  
        return TRUE;
    }



    BOOL EncryptString(TCHAR* szPassword,TCHAR* szEncryptPwd,TCHAR *szKey)
    {   
        BOOL bResult = TRUE;    
        HKEY hRegKey = NULL;    
        HCRYPTPROV hProv;   
        HCRYPTKEY hKey;
        HCRYPTKEY hXchgKey; 
        HCRYPTHASH hHash;   
        DWORD dwLength;
        // Get handle to user default provider.
        if (CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))  
        {
            // Create hash object.      
            if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))     
            {
                // Hash password string.            
                dwLength = sizeof(TCHAR)*_tcslen(szKey);
                if (CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE *)szKey, dwLength, 0))           
                {
                    // Create block cipher session key based on hash of the password.
                    if (CryptDeriveKey(hProv, MY_ENCRYPT, hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))              
                    {
                        // Determine number of bytes to encrypt at a time.
                        dwLength = sizeof(TCHAR)*_tcslen(szPassword);                   
                        // Allocate memory.
                        BYTE *pbBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(dwLength);                  
                        if (pbBuffer != NULL)                   
                        {
                            memcpy(pbBuffer, szPassword, dwLength);                     
                            // Encrypt data
                            if (CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, pbBuffer, &dwLength, dwLength))                      
                            {
                                // return encrypted string
                                memcpy(szEncryptPwd, pbBuffer, dwLength);

                            }   
                            else                        
                            {                           
                                bResult = FALSE;                        
                            }                       
                            // Free memory
                            free(pbBuffer);                 
                        }
                        else                    
                        {                       
                            bResult = FALSE;                    
                        }
                        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);  // Release provider handle.             
                    }               
                    else                
                    {
                        // Error during CryptDeriveKey!                 
                        bResult = FALSE;                
                    }           
                }           
                else            
                {
                    // Error during CryptHashData!              
                    bResult = FALSE;            
                }
                CryptDestroyHash(hHash); 
                // Destroy session key.     
            }       
            else        
            {
                // Error during CryptCreateHash!            
                bResult = FALSE;        
            }
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);  
        }   
        return bResult;
    }



    BOOL DecryptString(TCHAR* szEncryptPwd,TCHAR* szPassword,TCHAR *szKey) 
    {   
        BOOL bResult = TRUE;    
        HCRYPTPROV hProv;       
        HCRYPTKEY hKey;     
        HCRYPTKEY hXchgKey;
        HCRYPTHASH hHash;
        TCHAR szPasswordTemp[32] = _T("");
        DWORD dwLength;
        // Get handle to user default provider.
        if (CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))      
        {
            // Create hash object.          
            if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
            {               
                // Hash password string.
                dwLength = sizeof(TCHAR)*_tcslen(szKey);
                if (CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE *)szKey, dwLength, 0))               
                {
                    // Create block cipher session key based on hash of the password.
                    if (CryptDeriveKey(
                        hProv, MY_ENCRYPT, hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))                 
                    {
                        // we know the encrypted password and the length
                        dwLength = sizeof(TCHAR)*_tcslen(szEncryptPwd);                     
                        // copy encrypted password to temporary TCHAR
                        _tcscpy(szPasswordTemp,szEncryptPwd);
                        if (!CryptDecrypt(
                                hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, (BYTE *)szPasswordTemp, &dwLength))
                            bResult = FALSE;                        
                        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);  // Release provider handle.                 
                        // copy decrypted password to outparameter
                        _tcscpy(szPassword,szPasswordTemp);
                    }                   
                    else                    
                    {
                        // Error during CryptDeriveKey!                     
                        bResult = FALSE;                    
                    }               
                }               
                else
                {                   
                    // Error during CryptHashData!                  
                    bResult = FALSE;                
                }
                CryptDestroyHash(hHash); // Destroy session key.            
            }           
            else            
            {
                // Error during CryptCreateHash!                
                bResult = FALSE;            
            }
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);      
        }       
        return bResult;
    }
```

And this is how I call it :

```
TCHAR szEncrypt[32] = _T("");
EncryptString( myString, szEncrypt, szKey );

TCHAR szDecrypt[32] = _T("");
DecryptString( szEncrypt, szDecrypt, szKey);
```

*Note: The code is not mine.*

**EDIT: using key "Mz6@a0i*" turns Kolaris to Kolari**

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output?

Comment: @Duncan Jones I have updated the above post to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

The encrypted string can contain a zero byte, in fact the chances are 1/256 for any individual byte to be zero. You're assuming the encrypted result is a string which ends on a zero byte. Even if the TCHAR is 16 bits rather than 8, your chances are still 1/65536.

You need to pass the length of the encrypted result.

Comment: It works when I pass the length+1 but not when I only pass length.I tried both strlen() with char* and string.lenght() with std::strings.While passing length+1 If the original string has a white space in it like "Kola ris" then the output has one extra character at the end. Totally confused now.

Comment: @StudentX, if you change the input *in any way* the output will change as well and probably won't contain the null any more. It's the length of the *result* that needs to be kept intact, the encryption function should return that to you somehow.